# SWT GridLayout columns overlap

Tags: java, swt, grid-layout

**Code:**

```
final Composite sectionClient = toolkit.createComposite(parent, SWT.NONE);
sectionClient.setLayout(UIHelper.getLayoutForWidgets(new GridLayout(2, true)));
sectionClient.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

final Composite leftColumnComposite = toolkit.createComposite(sectionClient);
leftColumnComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, false));
leftColumnComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

final Composite rightColumnComposite = toolkit.createComposite(sectionClient);
rightColumnComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, false));
rightColumnComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

---

**Before:** 
[image]

**After:** 
[image]

---

**Description:** 
When window is minimized (i.e. user progressively minimizes it), the right column overlaps the left column. Given the layout of the containers, I would expect the columns not to overlap. Even some of the widgets become hidden.

What am I missing? I'm opened to a different approach on laying out the components.

---

**SSCCE / Lots of boiler-plate code (all elements are from [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)):**

```
/**
 * 
 * @author ggrec
 *
 */
public class ILovePancakes
{
    private FormToolkit toolkit;

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        new ILovePancakes();
    }

    private ILovePancakes() 
    {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        toolkit = new FormToolkit(display);

        createWidgets(shell);

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if ( !display.readAndDispatch() )
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private void createWidgets(final Composite parent)
    {
        // Main section
        final Section section = toolkit.createSection(parent, ExpandableComposite.COMPACT | ExpandableComposite.TITLE_BAR);
        section.setText("Main section");
        section.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        section.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        // Section client
        final Composite sectionClient = toolkit.createComposite(section, SWT.NONE);
        sectionClient.setLayout(UIHelper.getLayoutForWidgets(new GridLayout(2, true)));
        sectionClient.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        section.setClient(sectionClient);

        // --------------------- <Left Column> -----------------------

        final Composite leftColumnComposite = toolkit.createComposite(sectionClient);
        leftColumnComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, false));
        leftColumnComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        // Name
        final Label label_1 = new Label(leftColumnComposite, SWT.NONE);
        label_1.setText("Name");
        final Text nameWidget = new Text(leftColumnComposite, SWT.BORDER);
        nameWidget.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 4, 1));

        // P&L
        final Label label_2 = new Label(leftColumnComposite, SWT.NONE);
        label_2.setText("Profit and Loss");
        final Combo pnlFilterWidget = new Combo(leftColumnComposite, SWT.BORDER);
        pnlFilterWidget.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));

        // Background color
        final Label label_3 = new Label(leftColumnComposite, SWT.NONE);
        label_3.setText("Bkg color");
        final Button bkgColorSelector = new Button(leftColumnComposite, SWT.PUSH);
        bkgColorSelector.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));

        // Clear bkgColor button
        final Button clearBkgColorButton = new Button(leftColumnComposite, SWT.PUSH);
        clearBkgColorButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));

        // --------------------- <Right Column> -----------------------

        final Composite rightColumnComposite = toolkit.createComposite(sectionClient);
        rightColumnComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, false));
        rightColumnComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        // Code 
        final Label label_4 = new Label(rightColumnComposite, SWT.NONE);
        label_4.setText("Code");
        final Text codeWidget = new Text(rightColumnComposite, SWT.BORDER);
        codeWidget.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 4, 1));

        // Font Style
        final Label label_5 = new Label(rightColumnComposite, SWT.NONE);
        label_5.setText("Font Style");
        final Combo fontStyleWidget = new Combo(rightColumnComposite, SWT.BORDER);
        fontStyleWidget.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));

        // Font color
        final Label label_6 = new Label(rightColumnComposite, SWT.NONE);
        label_6.setText("Font color");
        final Button fontColorSelector = new Button(rightColumnComposite, SWT.PUSH);
        fontColorSelector.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));

        // Clear fontColor button
        final Button clearFontColorButton = new Button(rightColumnComposite, SWT.PUSH);
        clearFontColorButton.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
    }
}
```

Comment: Returns a layout which sets the horizontal spacing to 10. No other values of the layout are changed.

Comment: Ok, do you add any size constraints to the `Widget`s in each of the `Composite`s? BWT: Try removing the `UIHelper` stuff just to make sure.

Comment: No size constraints on the widgets. `GridData`s on all of them, with FILL, FILL, true, false.

Comment: Weird, can you create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows this behavior?

Comment: Added SSCCE. In this example, I noticed that my *issue* occurs at a smaller window size - this is because the combo widgets are empty. They know how to resize when you fill them with elements. Basically, the problem is still there even when using SWT widgets directly.

Comment: With the code you provided, I can see that it reduces size of all the widgets until the `Label`s would have to shrink. Starting from this point it the overlap you can see occurs. Not sure why this is though...

Comment: I think `ScrolledComposite` is the best solution, though I wanted to see what others think.

Comment: If you eventually find a solution, please post it here.