# SWT GridLayout column does not resize when widget size changes

Tags: java, swt

I have an SWT GridLayout consisting of two columns.  One column is a Label, and it should be exactly the size of its text horizontally.  The other column is a StyledText, and it should take up the rest of the horizontal space.  However, if the size of the label changes (because the text changed) the grid does not resize.  This results in the Label overlapping the StyledText.  What I want is for the grid to resize the columns, so that the left column gets large enough to hold the longer text, and the right hand column shrinks by exactly that amount.  There are several questions about SWT GridLayouts and resizing on SO, but none of them address the problem.  The one titled [SWT GridLayout columns overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440195/swt-gridlayout-columns-overlap) seems like a winner, except that it isn't quite exactly the same and there's no actual answer.
Here's a picture of the [Overlapping GridLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffucC.png)

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font;

final class GridOverlap{
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);

    shell.setLayout(layout);

    Label rows = new Label(shell, SWT.RIGHT);
    rows.setText("1");
    GridData rowsLayoutData = new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.FILL, false, true);
    rows.setLayoutData(rowsLayoutData);
    
    StyledText editor = new StyledText(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    GridData editorLayoutData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    editor.setLayoutData(editorLayoutData);
    editor.setText("Overlapped");

    shell.open();

    // This is where the problem is.
    rows.setText("1000\n999");
    rows.pack();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()){
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the shell to recalculate the layout of the entire shell to take account of the change size.

Use

```
shell.layout();
```

instead of the `rows.pack()`